How to use updateTransform to do something every frame/render WITHOUT moving the sprite? (or is there a better callback?) (Using ReactPixi)
Pixi.js added an onRender callback that is called every frame in v8, however ReactPixi seems to only have support for Pixi.js v7, so I have to use updateTransform. (I'm using ReactPixi). The documentation below states about updateTransform - "many people used this function to do custom logic every frame"
https://pixijs.com/8.x/guides/migrations/v8?_highlight=onrender#other-breaking-changes
Also, how do I actually use updateTransform? (what arguments does it take, what does it do, etc..) I couldn't find any documentation on it,
except this which doesnt explain anything... https://pixijs.download/v4.8.9/docs/PIXI.TransformBase.html#updateTransform
The tricky thing is - I don't actually want my sprite to move every frame... I'm really just looking for a callback to do something ELSE every frame, and I noticed that updateTransform moves my sprite even if I dont pass it any arguments. Is there a different callback I should use? Also, is it possible to use updateTransform without it moving my sprite?
Thanks!
I tried this but arg was undefined and I have no idea how to use the method... thanks!
 <Sprite
            image={"../images/blue.png"}
            width={100}
            height={100}
            x={100}
            y={100}
            anchor={0.5}
            interactive={true}
            pointerdown={onDragStart}
            pointerup={onDragEnd}
            pointerupoutside={onDragEnd}
            pointermove={onDragMove} 
            rightdown={right}
            rightdowncapture={right2}
            updateTransform={(arg) => {
              console.log(arg)
            }}
          />

